# I got an error when using double quotes in input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my template, there is a code that outputs variations selector. Page crashes when a user enters variation like 10" x 15".

I see that problem is in this part of code value="' + variant.options[i] +'"
I tried using replace() for removing double quotes and it's ok. But I want to show double-quotes. How to avoid the error without trimming double quotes?

```js
if (variant) {
  var form = jQuery('#' + selector.domIdPrefix).closest('form');
  for (var i = 0, length = variant.options.length; i < length; i++) {

    var radioButton = form.find('.swatch[data-option-index="' + i + '"] :radio[value="' + variant.options[i] + '"]');
    if (radioButton.length) {
      radioButton.get(0).checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have a look at "template literals", which allow for any type of quote marks.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML in the HTML pane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS.escape and template literals

```js
if (variant) {
  var form = jQuery('#' + selector.domIdPrefix).closest('form');
  variant.options.forEach((opt,i) => {
    const radioButton = form
      .find(`.swatch[data-option-index=${i}] :radio[value="${CSS.escape(opt)}"]`);
    if (radioButton.length) {
      radioButton.eq(0).prop("checked",true);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use back ticks instead for easy use.

```
var radioButton = form.find(`.swatch[data-option-index="${i}"] :radio[value="${variant.options[i]}]"`);
```